# jquery autocomplete dropdown to populate on click

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, click

I am using jquery autocomplete to populate a dropdown list.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#area").autocomplete( 
     { 

     source: "get_areas", 
     messages: 
     { 
     noResults: '', 
     results: function() {} 
     }, 
     select: function( event, ui ) 
         { 
          var selectedObj = ui.item; 
          var selectedobjectorder = selectedObj.value
          var substr = selectedobjectorder.split(': ');
          $('input[name^="selectedarea"]').val(substr[0]);
          var area=substr[0];

                  //get table data from DB
                  $.post("get_find_demand_all", { vararea:area, varperiod: $('#period').val()}).done(function(data) { 
                    $('#results').html(data);
                  }); 
         }
     });
});
</script>
```

This works 100% as desired. what I want though is to also populate the dropdown with all options when the dropdown list is clicked.

currently the user has to enter a string to trigger the population. is it possible to populate the field with all entries on click? to filter the dropdown the user can then enter some string and repopulate the dropdown with the results?

my database query `get_areas` is effectively:
`select distinct(area) from customer_address where area like %inserted string%`

SQL does return all rows for `like '%%'`

How can I modify the jquery for this?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [search](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) method to manually trigger search

Note: You need to set the [minLength](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength) option to `0` otherwise the default search will not work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#area").autocomplete({ 
        minLength: 0,
        source: "get_areas", 
        messages: 
        { 
            noResults: '', 
            results: function() {} 
        }, 
        select: function( event, ui ) 
        { 
            var selectedObj = ui.item; 
            var selectedobjectorder = selectedObj.value
            var substr = selectedobjectorder.split(': ');
            $('input[name^="selectedarea"]').val(substr[0]);
            var area=substr[0];

            //get table data from DB
            $.post("get_find_demand_all", { vararea:area, varperiod: $('#period').val()}).done(function(data) { 
                $('#results').html(data);
            }); 
        }
    }).click(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete('search', '')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
jQuery('#area').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).val('');
        jQuery(this).keydown();
    });
```